# Running Wordpress subdirectory with NGinx

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I have a website that relies on NGINX. The Wordpress part resides in a subdirectory. The configuration file I am using works just fine for (website)/portal/wp-json. It works just fine for (website)/portal/es, which is the Spanish translation. But it does not work for anything inside wp-admin. When I try to access anything inside wp-admin, I end up downloading the wp-admin.php file.

The conf file is set up to redirect to the portal subdirectory when a user visits the main part of the website. The second part is there to deal with wordpress subdirectories, like wp-json, wp-admin, but it fails with everything inside the administrator.

This is the conf file:

```
    location = / {
      try_files $uri $uri/portal /portal/index.php?$args;
      client_max_body_size 20M;
    }
    
    location ~ ^/portal/(.+?)/(.*)$ {
       try_files $uri $uri/ /portal/index.php$is_args$args;
    }
    
    location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
         client_max_body_size 20M;
    }
```

Comment: Where is your administrator?  is it at `(website)/administrator` or at `(website)/portal/administrator` ?

Comment: (website)/portal/wp-admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order matters; Nginx will apply priority from the order.

Try this and see how it looks:

```
location ~ ^/wp-admin/(.+?)/(.*)$ {
     try_files $uri $uri/ /portal/wp-admin/index.php;
     client_max_body_size 20M;
}

location ~ ^/portal/(.+?)/(.*)$ {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /portal/index.php$is_args$args;
}

location = / {
  try_files $uri $uri/portal /portal/index.php?$args;
  client_max_body_size 20M;
}
```